# How to pass params into history push

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a click handler here that is supposed to help me redirect the page upon clicking the item in the list.

## Expectations:

```
onRowClick: (rowIndex) =>this.props.history.push( {pathname: '/tickets',  param: rowIndex[0]};
```

Of course however, the code won't work. rowIndex is the param that I wish to pass into the url.

this is the history as logged in my console:

```
action: "POP"
block: ƒ block(prompt)
createHref: ƒ createHref(location)
go: ƒ go(n)
goBack: ƒ goBack()
goForward: ƒ goForward()
length: 50
listen: ƒ listen(listener)
location: {pathname: "/tickets", search: "", hash: "#/", state: undefined}
push: ƒ push(path, state)
replace: ƒ replace(path, state)
__proto__: Object
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
onRowClick: (rowIndex) =>this.props.history.push({pathname: '/tickets' , id: rowIndex[0]})
```

however there doesn't seem to have an effect upon clicking

Comment: What is `this.props.history`? Is this connected to a particular router, like `react-router`? How are the routes defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you simple fetch the param ID using match.

Example:

**Your Route**

```
<Route path="/tickets/:id" component={Tickets} />
```

**onClick**

```
this.props.history.push(`/tickets/${rowIndex[0]}`);
```

And then in the Tickets Component, fetch the param Id using match

**Tickets Component**

```
console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying this works , i must have had a typo previously as the str literals did not work , its working good now!

Comment: Awsome, Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, if you don't want to show your data in the URL, you can pass it in state:

```
this.props.history.push('/tickets', { data: rowIndex[0] })
```

or

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/tickets',
  state: {
    data: rowIndex[0],
  },
})
```

And in the Component, to get the data:

```
const data = this.props.history.location.state?.data
```

Read more: [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) and [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: I think this way is better than passing param using match, cuz what if somebody changes the URL manually? he in most cases will stay at the same page and the state will not change, but if you pass params at history.location you guarantee the user must click on the element to route to the component, other way he will get 404 page

Comment: @Anas Yes, you are right. But if you need your users to bookmark the URLs (along with the params), using params would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

try : `this.props.history.push('/tickets', rowIndex[0]):`
the syntax should be : `push(route, params)`

Comment: hey , i have tried this however there doesnt seem to have any effects

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'useHistory' from the library 'react-router-dom'if using functional component.

First initialize as below.

```
 const history = useHistory();
```

Then you can call whenever wanted

```
history.push('Path')
```

For example when clicking a button

```
onClick{()=>{history.push('/ticket')}}
```

Comment: Hey there , there's some states that im keeping with this component , therefore im using class based components,  have not yet looked into react,  is there a solution for this using class based comps?

Comment: There is another way to access the history.

You can pass the history to the child component from parent


<Child history={this.props.history} />

You can access the history.push from the child component. 

history.push('PATH')

Comment: @Abhijithv Your example does not consider params as the questions asks. How could It be used when we need to pass a param to another route?

Answer (score 1):

We can pass URL params in below format

```
 history.push({
  pathname: '/some-path',
  search: '?q=india&id=12345'
 })
```