# How to render API data in ReactJs by unique ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have a page where every data saved in the database is rendering in a table with very limited information, I have an action button (Detail) to view all the information for the particular company.
[image: Here is by table]

Code for the table:

```
const PendingApplication = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const handleClick = (location) => {
        console.log(location);
        history.push(location);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setData(response.data.kamData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Ticket No</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Sub Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Request Time & Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Company Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Action</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.approvecategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.subcategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.date}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Button color="#71BD44" onClick={() => handleClick('/detail')}>
                                    Detail
                                </Button>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PendingApplication;
```

Here is the code for detail page:

```
const Details = () => {
    const setPopup = useContext(SetPopupContext);
    let history = useHistory();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const handleClick = (location) => {
        console.log(location);
        history.push(location);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam/:id')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setData(response.data.kamData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Box
                sx={{
                    width: '90%',
                    padding: '24px 20px', // theme padding
                    border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
                    borderRadius: 4,
                }}
            >
                <div className="ticket-details">
                    <h3>TICKET DETAILS</h3>
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow>
                            <p>Ticket ID: {item.ticketno}</p>
                            <p>Category: {item.approvecategory}</p>
                            <p>Category: {item.subcategory}</p>
                            <p>Category: {item.date}</p>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className="additional-info">
                    <h3>ADDITONAL INFO</h3>
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow>
                            <p>Company Name: {item.companyname}</p>
                            <p>KCP Name: {item.kcpname}</p>
                            <p>KCP Contact No: {item.kcpcontact}</p>
                            <p>KCP NID No: {item.kcpnid}</p>
                            <p>No of MSISDN: {item.msisdn}</p>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Details;
```

I have created the API for unique ID, Here is the API:

```
router.get('/kam/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    kamForm
        .findById(req.params.id)
        .then((result) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                kamData: result,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                message: err,
            });
        });
});
```

After clicking the detail button i want that particular info in detail page, can anyone help me, how to do that?

Comment: Can you tell us what do you mean by "After clicking the detail button i want that particular info in detail page"? It seems like you want to navigate the user to a new page "localhost:3000/details" in the frontend which has data for that ticket, is that right? If that's the case please add a code snippet of your "Details" page

Comment: Yes, I want info by unique id On a new page In my case, it's "localhost:3000/details". I added the code snippet of my detail page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236196/how-to-pass-params-into-history-push

Answer (score 1):

In your Database, you must have an id column, send that column also with your data into fetch API. In your code, you will get **item.id**, use that id for the handleClick button.

see below code.

```
const PendingApplication = () => {
    let history = useHistory();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const handleClick = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
       //use id here 
        history.push(location);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/api/kam')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                setData(response.data.kamData);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Ticket No</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Sub Category</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Request Time & Date</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Company Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">Action</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {data.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableRow key={index}>
                            <TableCell>{item.ticketno}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.approvecategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.subcategory}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.date}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{item.companyname}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Button color="#71BD44" onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
                                    Detail
                                </Button>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PendingApplication;
```